# jquery one page scrolling with wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, scroll

**what I'm trying to do is get [this plugin](http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html) :**

**to work with [my page](http://thechrisbox.com/) :**

I get the overall way this plugin works, althought I'm not able to integrate it into my wordpress theme. I am guessing that I would need to write a PHP loop or something that counts every new section I create in wordpress and declares them .

Would someone be able to help me out here?

Thanks a lot and help is much apreciated

Comment: Include some of the code you have attempted so far.

Comment: well theoretically i have to declare every section with  
<section class="page1">
<section class="page2">
<section class="page3">

but since wordpress uses some code i cant really read and creates those sections through the wordpress dashboard I can't just add these section classes around each section manually, I basically don't even know where to start if that makes sense..